# CSS3 animation/transition in rect clip

Tags: css

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ckt1v3Lc/1/) jsfiddle code where, only with *css*, I'm tring apply a clip on a image but without any success.

I tried put a external div and applied the *clip* to this div that contains the images, but again without success.

Have anyone any idea why this is happening?

Follows the css code:

```
img{
  width:500px;
  height 100px;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);

}

#image{
   clip: rect(20px, 20px, 20px 20px);
}
```

Follows the html code:

```
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** [CSS `clip` property is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip) and should not be used.

The CSS `clip` property works only only absolutely positioned elements and so you either need to position the `#image` absolutely and apply the `clip` to it (or) position the `img` absolutely and apply the clip directly to it.

Other thing to note is that the arguments supplied to the `rect` function specify the offsets from the top-left border edge of the box. So, the values (`<top>`, `<right>`, `<bottom>`, `<left>`) should all be specified in such a way that they form a proper rectangle.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  clip: rect(0px, 20px, 20px, 0px);
}

#image {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg">
</div>
```

---

The `clip` property is transitionable/animatable as a `rect` and so it is possible to achieve something like in the below snippet.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  clip: rect(0px, 20px, 20px, 0px);
  transition: all 1s;
}

#image {
  position: relative;
}
#image:hover img {
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg">
</div>
```